# batchUpdate Not Sending

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-api-client, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets C# SDK client. I successfully initialized and read data from a spreadsheet using the `SheetsService` variable you see below.

The problem is I need to save back some data to specific columns. The method below takes in a record and is supposed to update the columns for that record's row but nothing is ever written. I also verified no traffic occurs in Fiddler when this method is run.

```
public static void Update(DataRecord record)
{
    var updateRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest()
    {
        ValueInputOption = "RAW",
        Data = new List<ValueRange>()
        {
            new ValueRange()
            {
                Range = $"'Form Responses'!C{record.RowId}",
                Values = new List<IList<object>>()
                {
                    new List<object>()
                    {
                        record.TransactionNumber
                    }
                }
            },
            new ValueRange()
            {
                Range = $"'Form Responses'!G{record.RowId}:I{record.RowId}",
                Values = new List<IList<object>>()
                {
                    new List<object>()
                    {
                        record.Name,
                        record.DateOfBirth,
                        record.Address
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    SheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(updateRequest, SpreadsheetId);
}
```

I also verified the scope of my SheetService is set to `SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets` and meticulously verified that I had the correct spreadsheet ID, tab name, and cell range selection.

What am I missing? Why is there no network traffic for a batch update but there is traffic for reading? There is no error. It simply completes and moves on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `.Execute()` call.  The last line should read:

`SheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(updateRequest, SpreadsheetId).Execute();`